# How to automatically copy the sqlite3 db file to /current in rails Capistrano deployment on ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano

Our rails 3.1.3 app running with sqlite3 and deployed with Capistrano on ubuntu. After each deployment, we have to manually copy the sqlite3 db file from previous release subdirectory to the /var/www/app/current. Is there a way (code example please) the deploy file can automatically copy the db file into the current subdir? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

make a soft link to the sqlite3 file after each deployment.